IntegrityError at /Hod/Staff/Save_Notification NOT NULL constraint failed: app_staff_notification.message in DJANGO
I'm unsure if the problem is in the models.py or the values I put in the html code. Initially there was some kind of problem with the models migrating but I quitted it.
models.py
class Staff_Notification(models.Model):
    staff_id = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.staff_id.admin.first_name

urls.py
path('Hod/Staff/Send_Notification', Hod_Views.STAFF_SEND_NOTIFICATION, name='staff_send_notification'),
path('Hod/Staff/Save_Notification', Hod_Views.SAVE_STAFF_NOTIFICATION, name='save_staff_notification'),

Hod_Views.py
def SAVE_STAFF_NOTIFICATION(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        staff_id = request.POST.get('staff_id')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        staff = Staff.objects.get(admin = staff_id)
        notification = Staff_Notification(
            staff_id = staff,
            message = message,
        )
        notification.save()
        return redirect('staff_send_notification')

staff_notification.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <h3 class="page-title">Staff</h3>
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Staffs</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-auto text-right float-right ml-auto">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">View
                    All Notifications
                </button>
                <!--a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mr-2"-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'includes/messages.html' %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card card-table">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="table_id" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-center mb-0">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="table-group-divider">
                            {% for i in staff %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{i.id}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <h2 class="table-avatar">
                                        <a href="student-details.html" class="avatar avatar-sm mr-2"><img
                                                class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="/{{i.admin.profile_pic}}"
                                                alt="User Image"></a>
                                        <a href="student-details.html">{{i.admin.first_name}} {{i.admin.last_name}}</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{i.admin.email}}</td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data toggle="modal" data-target="#sendnotification-{{forloop.counter}}">Send Notification
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
{% for i in staff %}
<div class="modal fade" id="sendnotification-{{forloop.counter}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle1"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle1">Send Staff Notification To {{i.admin.first_name}} {{i.admin.last_name}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'save_staff_notification' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="staff_id" value="{{i.admin.id}}" hidden>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Notification</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Error:


It seems that the value of message that you are trying to save is empty (meaning None), and your field does not allow None or NULL.
Are you sure that you entered a text when submitting the HTML form in your modal?
One solution to catch this kind of error could be to add a default value in case it is empty, or raise an explicit error if it is empty (maybe using Django messages).
For example:
def SAVE_STAFF_NOTIFICATION(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        staff_id = request.POST.get('staff_id')
        # in case there is no 'message', here we use an empty string instead of 'None'
        # by adding a second argument to '.get()'
        message = request.POST.get('message', '')
        if len(message) == 0:
            messages.error(request, 'message cannot be empty')
            return redirect('staff_send_notification')
        ...

